# Boostrap 3: Click over button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-controller

I'm working on a web application which uses AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap. My app works fine with Firefox, but with Chrome or Chromium (my operation system is Ubuntu) when I click button, this click is not detected correctly. The click is detected but the object event is null or is not detected. As you can see, it only writes `evento:` but not the `id`. In Firefox it writes `evento:` and the `id` correctly.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<button id = "removeLeftTables" ng-click = "hmCtrl.changeView($event)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove " aria-hidden="true" style = "vertical-align: middle; font-size: 25px"></span>
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
self.changeView = function(event){
    console.log("evento: " + event.target.id);
    if (event.target.id == "removeLeftTables"){
        self.show_left_tables = false;
        self.style_left_content = "";
        self.style_right_content = "";
        self.style_tables_content = "";     
        self.cleanTabStyles();
    }

    if (event.target.id == "removeRightTables"){
        self.show_right_tables = false;
        self.style_right_content = "";
        self.style_left_content = "";
        self.style_tables_content = ""; 
        self.cleanTabStyles();
    }
}
```

I have made this plunker using the same code to check the error and it works: https://plnkr.co/edit/vbBhVCrkpLyRl63Lwlur

I don't understand anything. Why is it not working in my web application while in the plunker works fine? What happend?

**Edit 1**:
My goal is to get the id of the object over I have made a clic. With Firefox, Chrome and Chromium. Right now, the id from the event is retrieved only by Firefox. With Chrome and Chromium the event is fired by I can't retrieve the id from the object event.

Edit 2:
I have added a trace to my code to know is event variable is null or not and when I make click in Chrome o Chromium event variable is not null but the id is not detected!!!

```
    $scope.changeView = function(event){
    if (event == null)
        console.log("event is NULL");
    else
        console.log("event IS NOT NULL");
    console.log("evento: " + event.target.id);
    if (event.target.id == "removeLeftTables"){
        self.show_left_tables = false;
        self.style_left_content = "";
        self.style_right_content = "";
        self.style_tables_content = "";     
        self.cleanTabStyles();
    }

    if (event.target.id == "removeRightTables"){
        self.show_right_tables = false;
        self.style_right_content = "";
        self.style_left_content = "";
        self.style_tables_content = ""; 
        self.cleanTabStyles();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by `currentTarget`  instead of `target`. Because of `currentTarget` get the element whose event listeners triggered a specific event

```
self.changeView = function(event) {
    console.log("evento: " + event.currentTarget.id);
};
```

It may help you

Comment: Yeeeeeees!!!! It works fine with Firefox, Chrome and Chromium!!! Thank you so much for your appreciated help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at fixed fiddle:
https://plnkr.co/edit/QftJvAhSYmfq57zknWq8?p=preview

In common case you should use `$scope.checkClick()` in controllers instead of `this.checkClick()`:

```
$scope.checkClic = function(obj) {
    console.log("obj: " + obj);
};
```

and there is no point to call method in html like `ctrl.methodName()`.

You can just do:

```
<button ng-click = "checkClick('Button Clicked!!!')">
```

Using this allowed only at `services`.
Even in `factories` you shouldn't use `this` (use `return {a:..., b: function(){...}}` syntax.

In controllers or directives you should use `$scope` (or `scope` for directives) to provide your methods to html

Comment: OP is using controller as (alias) syntax in which `this` will refer to controller and any function or variable attached to `this` in controller should be accessible from view using alias name.

Comment: Thank you Sergey!!! But my goal is to detect the event and this is not detected even If I make the changes that you have been post. With your changes, in Firefox works fine, but in Chrome or Chomium doesn't work :(